# are the tense of the verbs true in each sentence?

Tags: grammar

are the tense of the verbs true in each sentence?

1-I think Jimmy did his duty as other police officers do.(simple past+simple present is true?)

2-I think he did the right thing because he is a police officer (simple past+present is true?)

Comment: Proofreading is off topic for this site. Please take the quick tour to learn more about us and how we can help you.

Comment: The tenses are never true or false. They can be used _correctly_ or not. I think you may find that [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) may be a better place for your question.